# How to make two vertical windows into horizontal in vim?

Tags: vim

This is not trivial case, so I show it by the screenshots. The first one is what I have:

[image]

And the second one is what I need:

[image]

I want to get the result by pressing some simple sequence like `^Wr`. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

The most quick way I found the following:

- For the same buffers (like in the screens): `^Wc`, `^Ws`
- For the two different buffers: `^Wc`, `^Ws`, `^^` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>)

Comment: Good question. The easiest way I know would be splitting the first and closing the middle column. Eager to see if someone has any other shortcut that I'm missing...

Comment: I've updated the question, see the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your cursor is on middle window. If I were you, I would do:

```
:wq "(or ZQ depends on if you want to save the buffer)
```

to close middle window. Now your cursor should be on your left window, then:

```
:sp #
```